# Auto-scroll in a nested list in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a chat list inside the full web app. the whole webpage is scrollable (picture included in the bottom).
and I want the messages list to scroll to bottom whenever new message arrives.

I achieved that by adding a reference to the last element in the list like this

```
<div ref={lastMessageRef} />
```

and scroll to it using this method

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (lastMessageRef.current) {
        lastMessageRef.current.scrollIntoView({ smooth: true })
    }
})
```

the problem is when I do that the whole webpage scrolls too and I don't want this behavior.

so what can I do to make only the chat part to scroll and the webpage still in its position.

[my demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFDYH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using

```
window.scrollTo(0, the position you want it to stay on)
```

like so

```
 useEffect(() => {
    
        if (lastMessageRef.current) {
            lastMessageRef.current.scrollIntoView({ smooth: true })
            window.scrollTo(0, offset)
        }
}, [messages])
```